# What are the steps to send a email from customer to an admin in magento2

Tags: email, frontend, magento2.2

My Requirement: I need to set **General feedback link** in **footer** in **frontview** , **After clicking that link it would show a form, After submitting a form it will send a email to magento admin**. Please help me What I need to do, How would I need to get the overview... Please provide me a solution

Comment: have you check Contact Us page? for eg. http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/contact/

Answer (score 0):

You could develop one of these:

1. develop an admin grid with a db table for saving these submissions throw controller, this way an admin could check all the submissions.
2. develop a controller for sending emails and pickup the "send to" info from custom config.
3. 1 & 2

regards!